# how to add UIButton to UIView with animation effect

Tags: ios

I have a UIView in that, I am going to add 15 UIButtons. If I have  written code like this

```
for(int i =0; i<15;i++)
{
    [self.view addSubview:[self.buttonsArray objectAtIndex;i]];
}
```

But I want to subview UIButtons one after other. something like animation  effect.How to achieve it.

Comment: But anyway, options: 1. stick in an `NSTimer` that you run 15 times with an interval you want your program to wait after it added one button, and each time it runs, add a button. 2. Use `dispatch_after()`, run 15 times, specify an increasing interval counting from the current date, etc...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

**in .h file**

```
NSTimer *timer;
int buttonNo;

@property (nonatomic,retain) NSTimer *timer;
```

**in .m file**

```
@synthesize timer;

-(void) viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    //start your timer where you write your for loop
    buttonNo = 0;
    timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:3.0 target:self selector:@selector(addbuttons) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
} 


-(void) addbuttons {
    [self.view addSubview:[self.buttonsArray objectAtIndex;buttonNo]];
    buttonNo++;
    if (buttonNo == 15) {
        [timer invalidate];
        timer = nil;
    }
}
```

Comment: Aaaaand: `if (buttonNo > 15) [timer invalidate];`

Comment: in this case, take my upvote, this is exactly my 1st suggestion to OP.

Answer (score 1):

I would do it like this:

```
const float fadein_duration = 0.3f;
const float time_between_fadein = 0.15f;

int index = 0;
for (UIButton* button in self.buttonsArray)
{
    [self.view addSubview:button];
    button.alpha = 0.0f;
    [UIView animateWithDuration:fadein_duration delay:(index * time_between_fadein) options:0 animations:^{
        button.alpha = 1.0f;
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        // Do something maybe?
    }];
    index++;
 }
```

Currently, the animation is to fade-in, but you should be able to adapt it to other types of animations.

There are 2 constants right now which you can use to control the duration of the fadein, and the time between the appearance of 2 buttons.

Make sure you set the correct frames for the buttons when you create them. Otherwise, you will just get a bunch of overlapping buttons. If you need you can set the position of the buttons dynamically when you add them to the subview.

Also, I changed the loop mode to use a fast iterator over the array, and keep a incremental index manually.

Comment: Thank you. It is pretty compact and only uses local variables (no class variables needed).

Comment: You mean instance variables?

Answer (score 0):

Im Unsure of what you mean. As for annimation EFFECT, you may want to implement some type of timer, otherwise they will all be added at the same time

Answer (score 0):

If you want a fade in kind of animation then you can achieve something like this -

```
for(int i =0; i<15;i++)
{
        [self.view addSubview:[self.buttonsArray objectAtIndex;i]];

        [self performSelector:@selector(showBtn:) withObject:self.buttonsArray objectAtIndex;i] afterDelay:interval];

        interval += 0.5f;
}

- (void) showBtn:(UIButton*) btn
{    
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5f];
    [btn setAlpha:1.0f];
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

i assume the default alpha of all buttons in array is 0.

Answer (score -1):

pls try this code

```
for(int i =0; i<15;i++) 
{

    [self.view addSubview:[self.buttonsArray objectAtIndex;i]]; 
    [self performSelector:@selector(your animated methode) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.1];

}
```

Comment: He can try it, but it won't be of any success.

Comment: then i am giving my suggestion then why given down vote @H2CO3